# get_by_id() not returning values

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2, app-engine-ndb

I am writing an application that shows the user a number of elements, where he has to select a few of them to process. When he does so, the application queries the *DB* for the rest of the data on these elements, and stacks them with their full data on the next page.

I made an *HTML* form loop with a checkbox next to each element, and then in *Python* I check for this checkbox's value to get the data.

**Even when I'm just trying to query the data, ndb doesn't return anything.**

`pitemkeys` are the ids for the elements to be queried.
 `inpochecks` is the checkbox variable.
`preqitems` is the dict to save the items after getting the data.

The next page queries nothing and is blank.

The comments are my original intended code, which produced lots of errors because of not querying anything.

```
    request_code = self.request.get_all('rcode')
    pitemkeys = self.request.get_all('pitemkey')
    inpochecks = self.request.get_all('inpo')
    preqitems = {}

    #idx = 0
    #for ix, pitemkey in enumerate(pitemkeys):
    #    if inpochecks[ix] == 'on':
    #        preqitems[idx] = Preqitems.get_by_id(pitemkey)
    #        preqitems[idx].rcode = request_code[ix]
    #        idx += 1

    for ix, pitemkey in enumerate(pitemkeys):
        preqitems[ix] = Preqitems.get_by_id(pitemkey)
        #preqitems[ix].rcode = request_code[ix]
```

**Update:** When trying

```
preqitems = ndb.get_multi([ndb.Key(Preqitems, k) for k in pitemkeys])
```

preqitems returns a list full of `None` values, as if the db couldn't find data for these keys.. I checked the keys and for some reason they are in unicode format, could that be the reason? They look like so.

```
[u'T-SQ-00301-0002-0001', u'U-T-MT-00334-0007-0002', u'U-T-MT-00334-0008-0001']
```

Comment: Well, are you sure you have data for these keys in the datastore? Where are the key values coming from?

Comment: I'm sure of that Daniel, but I think I have to add details for ancestors as well.. Apparently key names could be repeated if the parent is different. But I don't think that's the only issue :/

Comment: But that's why I asked how you were generating the values for the checkboxes. You should probably output the urlsafe value rather than whatever you're doing now.

Comment: At the end of your question you have listed what you call a set of "keys" but these are not keys, just manually created strings used as id's.  If you have created the `Preqitems` with ancestors you must also provide the ancestor.

Comment: You both are right. the checkboxes only returned an 'on' value if they were checked, I managed to use it, but my issue was querying the data itself.
The strings at the end are the IDs not the full keys, that's exactly what they are, but even when I included the ancestor it didn't query for some reason.
I worked around this by querying the whole part of the table that I needed using another variable then validated the ids I need using the checkboxes, which I gave a unique value that indicates the entity's row number.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to do: int(pitemkey) or str(pitemkey), depending if you are using integer or string id